# Excel massive issue with UDF values, returning #VALUE, not storing calculated values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, udf

since I updated my Excel sheets with UDFs I have massive problems.

I wanted to change my formulas only in one place (that is the UDF), instead of every columns containing the same formula of my sheets (which are actually 60, number rising).

- a) performance

`Application.Volatile` in the UDFs makes my entire Excel application very unperformant. On top it does not fix the issue.

- b) storing values

In my Excel table I got different columns which build on one another, e.g. column A contains a UDF which is returning a value, that is used in column B for calculation in another UDF.

A simple test doesn't fail:

| cell | formula | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | `=1` | 1 |
| A2 | `=foo(A1)` | 4 |
| A3 | `=bar(A1)` | 3 |
| A4 | `=foo(A3)` | 10 |

```
Public Function foo(n As Double) As Double
    foo = bar(n) + 1
End Function
Public Function bar(n As Double) As Double
    bar = n * 3
End Function
```

- c) getting the values in an overview sheet (`#VALUE!`)

My overview sheet with all the total sums and so on fails because of the other sheets containing the `#VALUE!` errors.

The Recalculating button doesn't do the trick.

If I go from my overview to sheet X, update everything, go back to overview, the values are correct. If I now switch back and forth between them it's correct.
But if I go to sheet Y, update the UDFs and then go back to my overview, only the values of Y are correct, the values of X are reset.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Maybe important:

- I got one cell which is changing the color of the worksheet-tab
- I use a lot of `INDIRECT()`, e.g. to get the unique name of the tables of each sheet
- A worksheet opening event does not do the trick `Application.CalculateFull` or `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` is only updating the overview sheet
- Most UDFs are called from inside named tables/ranges and using values from this tables.
- In some UDFs I am `set`ting a range to a named range (`set rngA = Range("A1")` or `= Range("SomeGlobalName")`), indirect range or column of the same table (`set rngB = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Range(Range("SomeCell").Value2 & "[SomeColumn]")`)*.

*To mention: The `Range("SomeCell").Value2` contains the name(d range) of the table.

**Edit**:
I think I figured it out. The problem is a formula or the `set` within a UDF which I mentioned at the very last point I did put under "Maybe important" list:

- `set rngB = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Range(Range("SomeCell").Value2 & "[SomeColumn]")`

I changed it a little bit to:
`Set rngB = Range(Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name & "!" & Range("SomeCell").Value2 & "[SomeColumn]")`, the values now get's stored but problem is, if I  go back to my overview sheet and save or reopen the workbook I get the `#VALUE!` error again.

I created some debugging messages and the UDF stops (when I am at the overview sheet) at the point I am `set`ting the `rngB`. The next debug message (after the `set`) is not getting printed.

My guess is that it's a problem with `set`ting a `range` inside a UDF, whether it's named or not. I didn't figure it out yet. The error does not happen when I pass the range as a parameter or when the range is never set inside the UDF. I got certain break out points (`Exit Function`) inside the UDFs for performance reasons.

Microsoft is doing a really great job at helping users debugging UDFs with no error message appearing.

**Edit2**:
The error does not appear if I use evaluate: `Set rngB = Evaluate(Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name & "!" & Range("SomeCell").Value2 & "[SomeColumn]")`. Now the overview sheet is updated properly.

Comment: If whatever follows "I think I figured it out" is the solution, then post it as an answer (you may answer your own question) and mark the problem as solved

Comment: I would have if I had fixed all problems., thats because I wrote "I think.". Further investigation is needed, because I have still some errors.